# Using struct to display military time and add one second to user input (C++)

Tags: c++, struct

Last class we covered structs and even though my code feels complete to me, I am not understanding the errors I am getting. I have tried troubleshooting my code function by function in another instance of Visual Studio to no avail. I thought I might have been missing a couple header files, but I have just as many as my professor's lecture notes and examples.

Errors:

Stuck inside of `getTime` while loop

The objective is to write a program that prompts the user for the hours, minutes, and seconds for a 24-hour time (military time). If the time entered is valid, then one second is added to it, and the new time is output to the screen. I will post step by step instructions below the section with my code.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct Time
{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

void getTime(struct Time& time);
bool isTimeValid(struct Time& time);
void addOneSecond(struct Time& time);
void displayTime(struct Time& time);

const int MAX_HOURS = 23;
const int MAX_MINS = 59;
const int MAX_SECS = 59;

int main()
{
    Time time;

    char choice = 'Y';

    do
    {
        system("CLS");
        getTime(time);
        isTimeValid(time);
        addOneSecond(time);
        displayTime(time);
    } while (toupper(choice == 'Y'));

    return 0;
}
void getTime(Time& time)
{
    do {

        cout << "Enter the time in \"military time\", (24-hour format), in the following\norder : HH:MM:SS, (Hours, Minutes, Seconds).\nHours: ";
        cin >> time.hours;
        cout << "\nMinutes: ";
        cin >> time.minutes;
        cout << "\nSeconds: ";
        cin >> time.seconds;

    } while (isTimeValid (time));
}
bool isTimeValid(Time& time)
{
    if ((time.hours >= 0) && (time.hours <= MAX_HOURS) && (time.minutes >= 0) && (time.minutes <= MAX_MINS) && (time.seconds >= 0) && (time.seconds <= MAX_SECS))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    { 
        return false;
        cout << "Invalid Time";
    }
}
void addOneSecond(Time& time)
{
    time.seconds++;

    if (time.seconds > MAX_SECS)
    {
    time.seconds = 0;
    time.minutes++;
    }

    if (time.minutes > MAX_MINS)
    {
    time.minutes = 0;
    time.hours++;
    }
    if (time.hours > MAX_HOURS)
    {
        time.hours = 0;
    }
}
void displayTime(Time& times)
{
    char choice = 'Y';
    cout << "\nAfter adding one second, the time is " << setw(2) << cout.fill('0') << time << ".";
    cout << "Do it again? (Y/N)";
    cin >> choice;
}
```

Step by Step Instructions:

> Declare a struct named: Time
>
> The struct has 3 data members: hours, minutes, and seconds (all
>   integers)
>
> In main(), declare an object of Time and name it: time
>
> Four functions in the program:
>
> 1.) getTime – A void-returning function, gets input from user.
>
> The object, time, is passed by reference to the function.
>
> Note: Objects of structs and classes are always passed by reference.
>
> The function prompts the user to enter the time.
>
> The function reads the time entered by the user.
>
> The function returns no value.
>
> 2.) isTimeValid - Function returns a bool data type (true or false).
>
> The function is called from the getTime function.
>
> The parameter for this function is the time object that holds the
>   hours, minutes, and seconds representing the time entered by the user.
>
> This function checks to make sure the time entered is valid. (if the
>   time entered is invalid, return false, else return true)
>
> Include these global constants:
>
> MAX_HOURS = 23;
>
> MAX_MINS = 59;
>
> MAX_SECS = 59;
>
> If the function returns true, the getTime function is done and program
>   execution returns to main().
>
> However, if the function returns false, then a message displays:
>   Invalid time
>
> Still within the getTime function, the user is again prompted for the
>   time.
>
> Again the time is read and passed to the isTimeValid function, and so
>   on.
>
> Therefore, a do-while (or while) loop must be included within the
>   getTime function.
>
> Within the loop, the user is prompted for a time, and the isTimeValid
>   function is called.
>
> 3.) addOneSecond – A void-returning function adds one second to the time entered.
>
> 4.) displayTime – A void-returning function displays the time after the second has been added.
>
> cout.fill(‘0’) - This library function will fill any empty spaces with
>   the specified character. It checks to see what setw is, and then fills
>   if needed.
>
> Include a do/while loop, along with system(“cls”) – (Allows user to
>   repeat program)
>
> **Correct Output:**
>
> Enter the time in "military time", (24-hour format), in the following
>   order: HH:MM:SS, (Hours, Minutes, Seconds).
>
> Hours: 14
>
> Minutes: 44
>
> Seconds: 22
>
> After adding one second, the time is 14:44:23.
>
> Do it again? (Y/N) y

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Jake  updated with a few types of the errors I am receiving

Comment: Try thomas's answer it is most likely correct

Comment: Unrelated, what are you using as a development environment? It can be very helpful while learning to use one of the heavier weight IDEs like Eclipse or Visual Studio. They will often tell you that you have made a mistake shortly after you type it.

Comment: @user4581301 Visual Studio. But sometimes following error instructions lead to additional errors, for example, it will ask me to put a `;` in a strange place and once I add said `;` another error appears

Comment: That it does. That's what I mean about errors concealing one another. The sooner you kill an error the better. In the old days you'd get 1 error, solve it, and find it was hiding hundreds more. Or that the hundred errors were the result of one typo making the compiler go nuts. It's best to eliminate error messages from the top of the file down just in case you're sweating over an error on line 997 that is simply a side effect of a mistake on line 2.

Comment: @user4581301 I feel as if I always get errors when creating prototypes and such no matter if they are right or wrong.

Comment: Most of the time you don't need prototypes. Put `main` at the bottom of the file and organize the other functions so that the each function is beneath the functions it needs. When that doesn't work, usually a circular reference, then use a prototype.

Comment: Make sure you clean up warning messages too. Compiler errors mean the compiler can't make a program. Warnings mean that while the compiler can make a program, it probably won't do what you want. Example: `while (isTimeValid == false);` compares a function against `true`. Not the value returned from calling the function, but the function itself. This is legal in C++ and sometimes it is what you want to do, but it's so damn rare that the compiler will flag it as something you should take a closer look at.

Comment: @user4581301 Not sure if that was a hypothetical example or a hint to change `(isTimeValid == false);` to `(isTimeValid != true);`. Speaking of `isTimeValid`, the else statement is creating the final 2 errors: "expected a statement" and "illegal else without matching if". I know that there is already an `if` and I know that else isn't required to have an expression to work

Comment: It's a hint to change `isTimeValid` to `isTimeValid(time)`. You need to call the function. The function call up a couple lines doesn't do anything. It tests that the time is valid and then throws away the result. You could fix that to keep the result and use it in the `while` or you could just call the function in the `while`.

Comment: @user4581301 Finally got it to compile!!! However, I'm stuck in the while loop inside of getTime

Comment: Now that it compiles, it's time to use the debugger. Place a breakpoint inside `getTime` and step through the function line by line. Keep an eye on the variables you are reading and make sure they are right. before you step, make sure you know what the program should do so you will know if it doesn't do it. When expectation does not match reality, you've usually found a bug. Helpful search term: Input Validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some issues I found.
1. Don't use `struct` when referring to variable types.
Incorrect: `void getTime(struct Time *time)`
Correct:   `void getTime(Time * time)`

2. Pass by reference, not pointer:
   `void getTime(Time& time)`
3. You need to use either `.` syntax to refer to members or `->`:
   `cin >> time->hours;` // if passed by pointer.
   `cin >> time.hours;` // if passed by reference.
4. Don't use type names when referring to variables.
   Incorrect:  `if ((int time.hours >= 0)`
   Corrected:  `if ((time->hours >= 0)`
5. Remember "." access when passed by reference, "->" when using pointers.

You should invest in a better text book or at least review the section on structures, classes, and pointers.

Comment: Hey thanks, this got rid of a few errors. I wrote down all your tips for future reference. Updated post with corrections. Any little bit helps!

Comment: @dribs it appears you have changed the function implementations, but left the forward declarations untouched. You must change both to match or remove the need for the prototypes by fully implementing the functions ahead of their first use. I prefer to do without the prototypes where I can because they are one more place I can make a mistake.

Comment: @dribs Recommend that you stop moving the goalposts by substantially changing the question. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: @user4581301 I updated the post with those exact corrections right before I read this haha. Also made a few additional corrections that cut the amount of errors in half. I appreciate your input though!

Comment: @dribs Understood, but you're slowly picking your way through making Thomas's answer incomprehensible. That's bad form. Recommend writing a lot less code between compiling and testing. The less code new you have to check, the easier it is to find and correct errors. In addition, bugs tend to build off and conceal one another, so fewer bugs is much easier to deal with. Last time I saw your code you had `while (toupper(choice == Y));` which should have the compiler whining. Instead of fixing this you appear to have added more code, compounding your problems.

Comment: @user4581301 `while(toupper(choice == Y));` has been unchanged although it is causing a few of my remaining errors and I understand that too much editing can become a bad thing but I have to wait 90minutes between posts. Again, appreciate your responses

Comment: Then use that time to sort out the incorrect brackets in `if ((time.hours >= 0) && (time.hours <= MAX_HOURS)) && ((time.minutes >= 0) && (time.minutes <= MAX_MINS)) && ((time.seconds >= 0) && (time.seconds <= MAX_SECS))` Rather than having one big long instruction, break it into multiple lines and line up all of the brackets so you can see where you've left some out.

Comment: @user4581301 Got it ! Down to 4 errors, this is getting exciting